# Runtime error with Angular 9 and Ivy: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined ; Zone

Tags: angular, angular9

We have an Angular 8 project with tests.  We are attempting to upgrade to Angular 9 and went through all the steps in https://update.angular.io/#8.0:9.0l3.  This all went smoothly, no issues.  The app compiles with no errors and all of the tests run fine.  We are getting this error at runtime.  When we turn off Ivy, it runs fine so definitely seems related to Ivy.

```
zone-evergreen.js:659 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at registerNgModuleType (core.js:35467)
at core.js:35485
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at registerNgModuleType (core.js:35481)
at core.js:35485
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at registerNgModuleType (core.js:35481)
at new NgModuleFactory$1 (core.js:35649)
at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (core.js:41403)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (core.js:41768) TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
at registerNgModuleType (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:41436:27)
at http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:41454:14
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at registerNgModuleType (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:41450:17)
at http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:41454:14
at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
at registerNgModuleType (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:41450:17)
at new NgModuleFactory$1 (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:41602:13)
at compileNgModuleFactory__POST_R3__ (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:46530:27)
at PlatformRef.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:8080/vendor.js:46859:16)
```

Comment: do you got any answer?

Comment: Looks similar to this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31314

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I try to run build `ng build --prod` for my Angular  app. And it clear show me what problem i have.You can try it to know what you need to fix.

Comment: perfect!!! running with build showed the error being angular-cc-library credit card package... TX!!!!

Comment: Thank you. I tried to run `ng build --prod` and found that the problem was with the package ngx-currency-mask, that was not compatible with Ivy. I just removed this package.

Comment: This worked perfectly. There was an old module that I wasn't using anymore but still had it mentioned in one of my modules. ng serve didn't even mention the error! But this one did.

Comment: I saw the error after running `ng serve`. I ran `ng serve --prod` and didn't see it. Running `ng serve` again worked fine. Does prod mode clear/rebuild some cache somewhere?

Comment: No way... ng build --prod compiles fine

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to track down the error.  I had to comment out all the imported modules in `app.component.ts`, `app.module.ts` and `shared.module.ts` and add each module back one at a time.  I finally narrowed it down to the include of `angular2-recaptcha`. That was including a module called `ReCaptchaModule`.  I'm currently researching how to upgrade or replace that.

Hopefully this is a good troubleshooting tip to others out there.

Comment: We ended up finishing the upgrade to Angular 9, but turning off Ivy for the time being until we can get our dependencies updated/upgraded.

Comment: yeah, it’s a big job in some apps!

Answer (score 3):

try and add `"enableIvy": true` in `ts.config` under `"angularCompilerOptions"` & run `ng serve` it would give you a more precise description about the error.

Comment: In my case enable Ivy was the solution. After the compilation with Ivy the error was FlexLayout library, I updated the Flex Layout version and then the error was solved.

Answer (score 1):

In alternative to

> I was finally able to track down the error. I had to comment out all the imported modules in app.component.ts, app.module.ts and shared.module.ts and add each module back one at a time. I finally narrowed it down to the include of angular2-recaptcha. That was including a module called ReCaptchaModule. I'm currently researching how to upgrade or replace that.
>
> Hopefully this is a good troubleshooting tip to others out there.

You can do 'ng build', in my case it showed that my version of *"angular2-multiselect-dropdown"* was't compatible with Ivy. Upgrading that package worked for me. So that's a pretty easy way to spot some incompatibility.

Comment: For me, keeping the Ivy enabled, both ng build & ng build --prod were successful but it fails when I do ng serve. Couldn't able to find the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the compilation of modules. Try clearing your `node_modules` and running:

`ngcc --properties main`

Per this comment: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/31314#issuecomment-562373301

Comment: yes, i had cleared out my node_modules by running:  npm ci

Answer (score 0):

For me, I checked whether the packages I have used are compatible with Angular9. Once I removed the incompatible packages, everything works.

note: I happened to use angular2-recaptcha as well, which is not compatible with Angular9.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone reading this and experiencing the same issue.

My solution was adding this to angular.json at build.options:

```
 "preserveSymlinks": true
```

Comment: Maybe angular.json. In any case it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

For me, ng build --prod, was throwing some 2000+ lines of errors. Most of these were even from angular built in features e.g. date pipe could not be found. Resolved by doing the following:

- ran "npx ngcc" to compile third party components to ivy.
- added a debug point in browser where the error was being thrown at in the image below
- this lead me to find the problematic plugin (which was ngx-slick in my case), but this was nowhere in the logs
- just updated this problematic plugin to the latest version, and voila!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This just happened for me on my **Mac today after updating to 11.3.1**.

I deleted `node_modules` folder and when I ran `npm i` it complained `No Xcode or CLT version.`

To resolve I ran

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

Refer to [this article](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/gyp-no-xcode-or-clt-version-detected-macos-catalina-anansewaa-38b536389e8d) for more information on this.